# Login as the only user

Tags: login, security, users

Repeated question. How to make login possible to a single (root, admin) user only?
(Ubuntu mate 20.04.3 LTS.)

Comment: You want to limit `sudo` commands to a single user account? Or you want to limit *all* logins to a single user account (meaning there is only one account on the system) that happens to have `sudo` privileges? 

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your explanation from the comment. Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Do I understand correct that "visitors" can somehow log in to your PC and you want to stop this? Is there a guest account without a password? Or do you want to log in as `root` and block all other users?

Comment: Please do not repeat the same question. Rather edit the old question and add more pertinent information. Was your laptop left unattended in a place when this happened? Do you have any remote access software such as a `ssh` server, `vnc` server, `xrdp` server installed in your laptop? Have you enabled the option to share your desktop with someone else remotely? Do you use AnyDesk or TeamViewer in this laptop? If you don't tell us these information and keep asking the same question again and again we can't help.

Comment: Instead of posting the same cryptically terse and uninformative question over and over, which obviously does not get you the result you seek, how about taking a few moments to explain what the problem you are actually having is, in enough detail that another person can understand it? Based on what you have actually posted, Occam's razor says the problem is that you changed your password and forgot what it was.

Answer (score 1):

Users have to be explicitly granted permission to act as root. The first user created during installation automatically is assigned root privileges. To make login possible to a single root user, just make sure any other user on the system is removed from the group `sudo`. In order to remove other human users from Ubuntu without removing any system users you can run the following command to list only the human users:

```
cut -d: -f1,3 /etc/passwd | egrep ':[0-9]{4}$' | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: You will need to take better control of your computer.

Comment: Prefer it or not, but this is how it works. Only a user with sudo permissions can change your user password, unless a system is hacked, of course.

Comment: Someone who has physical access to your computer *and* has some system skills will always be able to log in into recovery mode and change passwords of any user. There is no other way, except for sophisticated hacking over the network exploiting a vulnerability, if any. "Watch your computer" is really the only advise  I can give. This is what I know. Be patient: perhaps there *is* another possibility, and an answer may still come around, in which case I will delete this one.

Comment: Thanks. Probably, I'll have to get some notebook kept off from the Internet, just for my writer's work. And the old stuff I use now, for a short time online.

Answer (score 0):

in the config ssh on the path `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` we can let's define AllowUsers and DenyUsers